# перегрузка функции

Tags: devc++, c++

Добрый день, сообщество!

Только начал изучать с++, так что не обессудьте.

Читаю книгу "Программирование на С++. Дирк Хенкеманс, Марк Ли". В ней приведен следующий пример перегрузки функции:

```
int add (int a, int b) 
{
   return a + b; 
}

float add (float a, float b) 
{
   return a + b; 
}

int main(void) 
{
   cout << add(5,3); 
   cout << add(5.5, 4.7); 
   return 
}
```

Однако у меня этот код не компилируется. Компилятор *не понимает* эту конструкцию, и ругается: **call of overloaded `add(double, double)' is ambiguous**. Как так получается?

На некоторых форумах пишут, что компилятор с++ не может определить к чему отнести целое число - к int или к float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

потому что `5.5` - это `double`. а его пребразовать к float не получиться. Поэтому, либо пишите реализацию с `double`, либо вызывайте так:

```
 cout << add(5.5f, 4.7f);
```

UPD:

Почему именно `double`? все по стандарту - 2.14.4, подпункт 1, где сказано, что если есть вещественное число и у него нет суффикса  (одно из `f`, `F`, `l`, `L`), то это будет double.

Comment: ясно, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

А вообще перегрузка функций именно в таком виде немного корява. Ведь, что если вам понадобится перегрузка функции для 3-4 простых типов? Часто делают акцент на использование шаблонных функций:

```
template<class Res, class A, class B>
Res s(A a, B b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Использование:

```
cout<<s<double>(1,5.7)<<endl
    <<s<int>(1,5.7)<<endl;
```